# Создание конфигурационных файлов в Linux без прав root

Tags: c++, linux

Как создать конфигурационные файлы в Linux без root прав, и где создать папку под них, чтобы все пользователи могли получить к ней доступ?

Я предположил что можно создать эту папку в /home c помощью

```
File *fp = popen("mkdir resource","r")
```

Я создал папку в `/home`, но другие пользователи не могут получить к ней доступ без root прав, а также не получилось создать в ней документ (нужно имя user). Может быть в local есть специально предназначенные для этого папки?

Comment: Мне нужно сохранить ключ для моего прилождения,и затем уже при каждом запуске  сверять(если не совпадает то перезаписывать).На всех пользователях этот ключ одинаков(т.е под компьютер)

Comment: Изучайте https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0_unix

Comment: мне нужно это сделать без root

Comment: Это не требует root, изучайте внимательнее

Comment: Но вообще по-хорошему ваша задача должна выполняться именно через root, раз она касается всей системы и всех пользователей. Чем вам не угодил root? Достаточно рутом создать общий каталог с нужными правами на чтение-запись один раз при установке приложения, а дальше пользователи смогут получать к ней доступ без рута

Comment: Вы предложили хорошую идею про создание общего каталога с правами при установки.попробую

Comment: http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/Linux_Foundations/9/ch09.html#idp5785328 // или тут [другими словами](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/Linux_Foundations/9/ch09.html#idp5785328) (про тот же каталог — `/etc`)

Comment: @user334910 в /var/lib/имяпроги такие штуки кладут. Ключи и ресурсы лучше туда.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin etc больше для константных конфигов. Если оно обновляется пользователем, то мне кажется лучше в var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> где создать папку под них, чтобы все пользователи могли получить к ней
>   доступ?

1. Где угодно. Традиционно, конфигурационные файлы лежат либо в /etc либо в /usr/local/etc
2. Для раздачи прав доступа существует команда *chmod*

Т.е. простейший путь решения проблемы:

```
cd /usr/local/etc
sudo nano my_config.conf
sudo chmod 0666 my_config.conf
```

Абсолютно все пользователи будут видеть этот конфиг и смогут его править.

Но, на самом деле, это очень плохое решение... Любой идиот сможет этот конфиг изгадить. Поэтому, в люнихе, традиционно используется другой метод:

- Конфиг по умолчанию размещают в /etc. Его все видят, но никто не редактирует.
- При первом запуске приложения оно копирует дефаультовый конфиг в папку /home/login  Этот файл видит только хозяин, но может его править.